# How to get Bittrex trading data for 10 different coins?

Tags: api, trading, historical-trade-data, bittrex, bots

I am writing MATLAB code to get the trading data from Bittrex. I have 10 different coin trading volume data that I want to know. To do this, I have a few ideas but not work in Bittrex.

1. Use 'getmarkethistory' for each alt coin trading information for every second and then combine the data (This does not work because it will easily hit the rate limit)
2. Some other platform have 'heartbeat' functions. If you use the function, it makes sure you download all trade history. (This does not work because I could not find this function in Bittrex)

Would someone give me an idea of collecting data from Bittrex?

Comment: You are going to have a hard time pulling 10 requests per second. Do you need all the data? Won't the volume provided by the exchange per 24H be sufficient? You can try to [pull bittrex data from cryptocompare.com](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-data-histominute-) or see if the [Bittrex API v2](https://github.com/thebotguys/golang-bittrex-api/wiki/Bittrex-API-Reference-(Unofficial)) works better.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the data from 
https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries

You will get a dictionary including all markets volume data (and a lot other data ).
Just pick the 10 market you need.

Answer (score 0):

The Bittrex API is not updated every second so you will waste resources, and possibly get banned, if you try to get every market, every second. It is better to use a third-party service for this information, one without rate limits or cached data. I use [Cluedex.com](https://www.cluedex.com/api) for all of my Bittrex market data. There are no rate limits and they don't cache data.

Comment: cluedex is no longer being maintained